# Compilation error of java program : unmappable character for encoding UTF8

Tags: java, utf-8, hadoop, compiler-errors, mapreduce

I wrote this Java hadoop program which will execute parallel indexation of files.The file was created in eclipse

```
package org.myorg;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

public class ParallelIndexation {


public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> { 
     private final static IntWritable zero = new IntWritable(0); 
     private Text word = new Text();
     public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException { 
        String line = value.toString();
        int CountComputers;
        //DataInputStream ConfigFile = new DataInputStream( new FileInputStream("countcomputers.txt"));
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("/usr/countcomputers.txt"); // путь к файлу
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String result = br.readLine(); // читаем как строку
        CountComputers = Integer.parseInt(result); // переводим строку в число
        //CountComputers=ConfigFile.readInt();
        in.close();
        fstream.close();
        ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, "\n");
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) 
        {
          paths.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
        }
        String[] ConcatPaths= new String[CountComputers];
        int NumberOfElementConcatPaths=0;
        if (paths.size()%CountComputers==0)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<CountComputers; i++)
            {
                ConcatPaths[i]=paths.get(NumberOfElementConcatPaths);
                NumberOfElementConcatPaths+=paths.size()/CountComputers;
                for (int j=1; j<paths.size()/CountComputers; j++)
                {
                    ConcatPaths[i]+="\n"+paths.get(i*paths.size()/CountComputers+j);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NumberOfElementConcatPaths=0;
            for (int i=0; i<paths.size()%CountComputers; i++)
            {
                ConcatPaths[i]=paths.get(NumberOfElementConcatPaths);
                NumberOfElementConcatPaths+=paths.size()/CountComputers+1;              
                for (int j=1; j<paths.size()/CountComputers+1; j++)
                {
                    ConcatPaths[i]+="\n"+paths.get(i*(paths.size()/CountComputers+1)+j);
                }           
            }
            for (int k=paths.size()%CountComputers; k<CountComputers; k++)
            {
                ConcatPaths[k]=paths.get(NumberOfElementConcatPaths);
                NumberOfElementConcatPaths+=paths.size()/CountComputers;                
                for (int j=1; j<paths.size()/CountComputers; j++)
                {
                    ConcatPaths[k]+="\n"+paths.get((k-paths.size()%CountComputers)*paths.size()/CountComputers+paths.size()%CountComputers*(paths.size()/CountComputers+1)+j);
                }                   
            }
        }
        //CountComputers=ConfigFile.readInt();
        for (int i=0; i<ConcatPaths.length; i++)
        {
            word.set(ConcatPaths[i]);
            output.collect(word, zero);
        }
     }
}



public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> { 
    public native long Traveser(String Path);
    public native void Configure(String Path);
    public void reduce(Text key, IntWritable value, OutputCollector<Text, LongWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException { 
        long count;
        String line = key.toString();
        ArrayList<String> ProcessedPaths = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, "\n");
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) 
        {
          ProcessedPaths.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
        }       
        Configure("/etc/nsindexer.conf");
        for (int i=0; i<ProcessedPaths.size(); i++)
        {
            count=Traveser(ProcessedPaths.get(i));
        }
        output.collect(key, new LongWritable(count));
      }
    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("nativelib");
    } 
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
      JobConf conf = new JobConf(ParallelIndexation.class); 
      conf.setJobName("parallelindexation");
      conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
      conf.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
      conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
      conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
      conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
      conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
      conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
      FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
      FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));
      JobClient.runJob(conf);
  } 
}
```

As a result of compilation in the Nexenta Illumos operating system (solaris) by means of team

```
javac -classpath hadoop-examples-1.0.1.jar -d folder/classes folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java,
```

received the following mistake

```
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:23: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("/usr/countcomputers.txt"); // ���� � �����
                                                                                     ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:23: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("/usr/countcomputers.txt"); // ���� � �����
                                                                                      ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:23: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("/usr/countcomputers.txt"); // ���� � �����
                                                                                       ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:23: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("/usr/countcomputers.txt"); // ���� � �����
                                                                                        ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:23: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("/usr/countcomputers.txt"); // ���� � �����
                                                                                          ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:23: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("/usr/countcomputers.txt"); // ���� � �����
                                                                                            ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:23: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("/usr/countcomputers.txt"); // ���� � �����
                                                                                             ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:23: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("/usr/countcomputers.txt"); // ���� � �����
                                                                                              ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:23: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("/usr/countcomputers.txt"); // ���� � �����
                                                                                               ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:23: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("/usr/countcomputers.txt"); // ���� � �����
                                                                                                ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:26: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        String result = br.readLine(); // ������ ��� ������
                                          ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:26: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        String result = br.readLine(); // ������ ��� ������
                                           ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:26: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        String result = br.readLine(); // ������ ��� ������
                                            ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:26: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        String result = br.readLine(); // ������ ��� ������
                                             ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:26: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        String result = br.readLine(); // ������ ��� ������
                                              ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:26: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        String result = br.readLine(); // ������ ��� ������
                                               ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:26: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        String result = br.readLine(); // ������ ��� ������
                                                 ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:26: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        String result = br.readLine(); // ������ ��� ������
                                                  ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:26: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        String result = br.readLine(); // ������ ��� ������
                                                   ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:26: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        String result = br.readLine(); // ������ ��� ������
                                                     ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:26: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        String result = br.readLine(); // ������ ��� ������
                                                      ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:26: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        String result = br.readLine(); // ������ ��� ������
                                                       ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:26: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        String result = br.readLine(); // ������ ��� ������
                                                        ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:26: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        String result = br.readLine(); // ������ ��� ������
                                                         ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:26: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        String result = br.readLine(); // ������ ��� ������
                                                          ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:27: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        CountComputers = Integer.parseInt(result); // ��������� ������ � �����
                                                      ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:27: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        CountComputers = Integer.parseInt(result); // ��������� ������ � �����
                                                       ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:27: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        CountComputers = Integer.parseInt(result); // ��������� ������ � �����
                                                        ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:27: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        CountComputers = Integer.parseInt(result); // ��������� ������ � �����
                                                         ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:27: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        CountComputers = Integer.parseInt(result); // ��������� ������ � �����
                                                          ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:27: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        CountComputers = Integer.parseInt(result); // ��������� ������ � �����
                                                           ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:27: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        CountComputers = Integer.parseInt(result); // ��������� ������ � �����
                                                            ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:27: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        CountComputers = Integer.parseInt(result); // ��������� ������ � �����
                                                             ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:27: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        CountComputers = Integer.parseInt(result); // ��������� ������ � �����
                                                              ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:27: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        CountComputers = Integer.parseInt(result); // ��������� ������ � �����
                                                                ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:27: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        CountComputers = Integer.parseInt(result); // ��������� ������ � �����
                                                                 ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:27: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        CountComputers = Integer.parseInt(result); // ��������� ������ � �����
                                                                  ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:27: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        CountComputers = Integer.parseInt(result); // ��������� ������ � �����
                                                                   ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:27: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        CountComputers = Integer.parseInt(result); // ��������� ������ � �����
                                                                    ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:27: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        CountComputers = Integer.parseInt(result); // ��������� ������ � �����
                                                                     ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:27: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        CountComputers = Integer.parseInt(result); // ��������� ������ � �����
                                                                       ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:27: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        CountComputers = Integer.parseInt(result); // ��������� ������ � �����
                                                                         ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:27: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        CountComputers = Integer.parseInt(result); // ��������� ������ � �����
                                                                          ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:27: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        CountComputers = Integer.parseInt(result); // ��������� ������ � �����
                                                                           ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:27: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        CountComputers = Integer.parseInt(result); // ��������� ������ � �����
                                                                            ^
folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:27: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
        CountComputers = Integer.parseInt(result); // ��������� ������ � �����
                                                                             ^
46 errors
```

How in eclipse to change the coding for UTF8?

Comment: I guess your commends are the source of the trouble

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, you can set the text file encoding in three places:

- At the workspace level: Preferences / General / Workspace / Text file encoding
- At the project level: Properties (on project) / Resource / Text file encoding
- At the file level: Properties (on file) / Resource / Text file encoding

I recommend to set it at workspace and project level and if only if necessary at file level.

Setting the file encoding doesn't really convert the file itself. You might need to use a separate tool (such as `iconv`) for that.

Comment: There's rarely a good reason to set this on the file-level: all files of inside a project should use the same encoding, as much as possible.

Comment: If you have a few files to convert, Notepad++ (http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) can do that for you, if it's an entire project I concur with the `iconv` route.

Answer (score 0):

Java 6 gives a "warning" for umappable characters.

Java 7 gives an "error" for umappable characters, and fails.

Check file encoding with

```
file -bi [filename]
```